# R: Calculate Standard Deviations by Group with a Moving Window

Tags: r, standard-deviation, panel-data

I would love to analyze **monthly stock returns** for **multiple companies** (Panel Data). However, I am struggling with calculating the **standard deviation** for the **last X months by company**.

Basically, I want to add another column to my existing data.frame, in which the standard deviation according to a moving window of X months by company is shown. Please find below a **simplified example** of my data and what I would love to achieve.

```
#My data:
company = c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","4")
return = c(0.01,0.015,-0.01,0.02,0.023,-0.04,-0.02,-0.01,0.05,0.06,0.03,-0.09,0.2,0.3,-0.04,-0.02,-0.01,0.023,-0.04)
stock = data.frame(company,return)
```

Given this initial situation, I would love to calculate the standard deviation in another column, based on e.g. 3 observations.

```
#Column to be filled with the respective value
stock["std_3obs"] = NA
#However, I do not manage to fill this column accordingly. The following result for a given row is expected:
#row 1 = Not possible, as there are not enough prior observations available
#row 2 = Not possible, as there are not enough prior observations available
#row 3 = sd(c(0.01,0.015,-0.01) = 0.01322876
#row 7 = Not possible, as there are not enough prior observations available
#row 8 = sd(c(-0.040,-0.020,-0.010)) = 0.01527525
```

Thanks a lot in advance! Any help is highly appreciated! Please be gentle, as I am fairly new to R.

***Side Note:**
*Research on this issue and adapting other solutions always lead to this error: replacement has X rows, data has Y * where X >>> Y*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the rolling functions from `zoo` package :

```
library(dplyr)

stock %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(std_3obs = zoo::rollapplyr(return, 3, sd, fill = NA))

#  company return std_3obs
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 1        0.01   NA     
# 2 1        0.015  NA     
# 3 1       -0.01    0.0132
# 4 1        0.02    0.0161
# 5 1        0.023   0.0182
# 6 2       -0.04   NA     
# 7 2       -0.02   NA     
# 8 2       -0.01    0.0153
# 9 2        0.05    0.0379
#10 2        0.06    0.0379
#11 2        0.03    0.0153
#12 2       -0.09    0.0794
#13 3        0.2    NA     
#14 3        0.3    NA     
#15 3       -0.04    0.175 
#16 3       -0.02    0.191 
#17 4       -0.01   NA     
#18 4        0.023  NA     
#19 4       -0.04    0.0315
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(stock)[, std_3obs := frollapply(return, 3, sd), by = company]
```

Output

```
> stock[]
    company return   std_3obs
 1:       1  0.010         NA
 2:       1  0.015         NA
 3:       1 -0.010 0.01322876
 4:       1  0.020 0.01607275
 5:       1  0.023 0.01824829
 6:       2 -0.040         NA
 7:       2 -0.020         NA
 8:       2 -0.010 0.01527525
 9:       2  0.050 0.03785939
10:       2  0.060 0.03785939
11:       2  0.030 0.01527525
12:       2 -0.090 0.07937254
13:       3  0.200         NA
14:       3  0.300         NA
15:       3 -0.040 0.17473790
16:       3 -0.020 0.19078784
17:       4 -0.010         NA
18:       4  0.023         NA
19:       4 -0.040 0.03151190
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks a lot!